# Compile and Publish Failure .Net Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have setup two machines to compile and publish a .netcore web application.

One seems to work OK, the other does not.

The problem machine claims to have succeeded with the build, but the publish fails because no DLL was produced.

The build/publish output is as follows, I would be very grateful on where I go from here to track down what is wrong

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Engine, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "C:\Users\Dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Engine\src\Engine" --configuration Release --no-dependencies
1>  Project Engine (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
1>  Compiling Engine for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
1>  Compilation succeeded
1>      0 Warning(s)
1>      0 Error(s)
1>  Time elapsed 00:00:00.9996920
1>
2>------ Publish started: Project: Engine, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Connecting to C:\Users\MHR\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Engine\src\Engine\.\bin\Release\PublishOutput...
Environment variables:
Path=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish "C:\Users\Dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Engine\src\Engine" --framework netcoreapp1.0 --output "C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\Engine75" --configuration Release --no-build
Publishing Engine for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Publishing.targets(149,5): Error : Could not find file 'C:\Users\Dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Engine\src\Engine\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.0\Engine.dll'.

2>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Machine is Windows 10 Pro, all updates installed.
IDE is Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Using .NetCore SDK version  1.0.0-preview2-003131

Comment: So it' complaining about a missing file: _C:\Users\Dev\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Engine\src\Engine\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.0\Engine.dll_ so it means that the build process doesn't output that file. maybe slightly different folder?

Comment: Can you post project.json of your Engine project?
What is the working dir?
Also, what do you get if "--no-build" is removed from `dotnet publish`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, please see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It is odd that the compiler claims the binary was built but yet the Publishing process claims it was not there.

By monitoring the build directory contents at compile time it became obvious that the DLL was being built, but then was immediately deleted.

A quick check of the Norton/Symantec virus checker running on this machine, showed that it was responsible for eating the DLLs.

There was nothing wrong with the development environment itself.

I added the project tree to the exclusion list for the virus checker and it all works fine now.